# Font type is different in html and canvas

Tags: angularjs, html2canvas

I'm using **html2canvas** lib to render my html page to image, and then I put that to PDF using **jspdf**. But somehow my html page font is different from the font in the PDF file.

```
$scope.ConvertToPdf = function(obj){
        $scope.downloadPdfArr = [];
        $scope.downloadPdfArr = angular.copy(obj);

        html2canvas($("#widget"),{
            onrendered : function(canvas){

                var imgData = canvas.toDataURL(
                    'image/png');              
                var doc = new jsPDF();
                doc.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 10, 10,200,100);
                doc.save('sample-file.pdf');


            }
        })
    }
```

This is my html page

[image: html page]

This is the PDF I'm getting

[image: PDF image]

Answer (score 0):

html2canvas does not claim to handle all types of [styling](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/faq.html) - if there is a font-style property on your page, perhaps it's not being handled correctly or at all. It can differ between browsers too - which browser are you using to get this result?

You can try debugging the html2canvas source in dev tools, such as the functions Font(family, size) and cloneNode(node, javascriptEnabled) to see how exactly the HTML of your page is being processed, and have a look inside the DOM node objects.